# Сложный GridView / RecyclerView с картинками

Tags: java, android, recyclerview, gridview

Есть данные в базе и с помощью их нужно создать GridView или RecyclerView не важно (суть одна что бы список был сортирован по категориям как на картинке собаки, кошки и т.д.). В базе данных есть колонка с категориями.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: и что у вас не получается?

Comment: Ну у меня список динамический

Comment: и чем мы можем вам помочь?

Comment: Нужно рассказать как реализовать такой макет как на картинке. Можно было бы просто накидать с помощью картинок, но у меня в БД таких 150 ячеек, и как бы использовать 150 imageVIew глупо да и низкоэффективна в плане производительности. Я умею создавать RecyclerView / GridView но как видите на картинки столбцы разделены по категориям, то есть кошки/собаки.. помимо трех этих у меня есть ещё пару категорий. Проблема в том что если заполнять через RcyclerView/GridView он делает сетку и заполняет их беспорядка (то есть по очереди). А мне нужно что бы RycylerViwe разделял на тематические столбцы.

Comment: что если сделать один RecycleView для каждой категории?

Comment: Ну допустим у меня 11 категорий видны сразу на одном экране это уже нагрузка на систему так как 11 адаптеров для этого нужно (ну или я если умудриться все сделать в одном то все равно сам метод findViewByID затратный при создании)